# Storing backreferences from regex expression for later use

Tags: java, regex, backreference

If I have,

```
String str = "11"; 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d)\\1"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
```

How do I store use the result of \1 later? For example I want to do,

```
String str = "123123"; 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d)\\1"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
String dependantString = //make this whatever was in group 1 of the pattern.
```

Is that possible?

Comment: @Jerry Any special reason why you post it as comment instead of answer? Do you want to collect [Peanut Gallery](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/peanut-gallery) hat?

Comment: @Pshemo Well... not really but it's like something which could have been obtained through search/google or reading the documentation =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first call `Matcher#find` and then `Matcher#group(1)` like this:

```
String str = "123123"; 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\1"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find())
    System.out.println( m.group(1) ); // 123
```

**PS:** Your regex also needed some correction to use `\\d+` instead of `\\d`.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Sorry for the lousy question, I'm still new to the regular expression business and hadn't touched upon that in my readings :)

Comment: Oh no problems at all, never feel bad/shy in asking questions. But yes make efforts to solve it too :)